# gnuplot oriented arrows on points

Tags: gnuplot

In order to draw a wind speed with the direction i try to find a way to draw the speed curve of the wind were each points will be arrows oriented in the wind direction.

The first solution that I have find is to plot vectors witch works really well still I keep standard axes.

Data :

```
#Steps Speeds m/s Directions °

0 3.2 56
```

with that command

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:(cos($3)):(sin($3)) with vectors head filled lt 2
```

I obtain a vector on each points with the wind direction.

My probleme is that I want to draw with time axis.. I get this way a different proportion between the 2 axis, so i dont have cercle anymore but a sort of elipse. The vectors get shorter for east and west.

Does someone see an issue, have idea solution. In the absolute I would like to do each or some point value appear like oriented arrow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the code i did,

```
    # Setting xdata to time.
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"

# set format x controls the way that gnuplot displays the dates on the x axis.
# "%Y-%m-%d" is the same as "%F", but "%F" applies to output only; it won't work
# for timefmt, which controls data reading.
set format x "%H:%M"

set xrange ["2018-10-23-06:00":"2018-10-23-19:00"]
#set yrange [0:12]

FILE="history_export_2018-11-06T13_23_09.dat"

set angles degrees
set grid mxtics mytics xtics ytics
set key outside  bmargin left spacing 1.8
set key maxrows 1
set ylabel 'Vitesse [Klm/s]'
set xlabel 'Temps [hh:mm]'
#set title "Simple Plots" 
set title  font "Arial,20" norotate
LEN=1.8

plot FILE using 1:3 with lines          # just to get the scaling
SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN))
#SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)) * (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN) * GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE
plot FILE using 1:3:(LEN*cos($4)*SCALE):(LEN*sin($4)) with vectors head filled lc 7 title"Directions" ,\
    FILE using 1:3 smooth csplines  title "Vitesse",\
    FILE using 1:5 smooth csplines t "Rafale"
```

And here some data

```
#Year-Month-Day-Hour:Minute Temperature  [2 m above gnd] Wind Speed  [10 m above gnd] Wind Direction  [10 m above gnd] Wind Gust  [sfc]
    2018-10-23-00:00 8.62 16.26 354.92 21.96
    2018-10-23-01:00 7.91 15.19 354.56 222.32
    2018-10-23-02:00 7.26 14.80 355.82 27.00
    2018-10-23-03:00 6.51 12.78 350.27 18.00
    2018-10-23-04:00 8.24 18.06 355.43 23.40
    2018-10-23-05:00 8.21 15.94 353.52 23.04
    2018-10-23-06:00 8.15 14.92 351.67 21.60
    2018-10-23-07:00 8.15 14.44 355.71 25.56
    2018-10-23-08:00 8.24 15.50 357.34 26.64
    2018-10-23-09:00 8.70 17.64 360.00 28.08
    2018-10-23-10:00 10.08 17.64 360.00 27.36
    2018-10-23-11:00 12.79 18.37 2.25 24.84
    2018-10-23-12:00 15.43 23.44 3.52 28.44
    2018-10-23-13:00 16.59 23.86 255.19 29.88
    2018-10-23-14:00 17.32 23.08 93.58 28.08
    2018-10-23-15:00 17.75 23.08 3.58 28.08
    2018-10-23-16:00 17.64 21.97 1.88 27.00
    2018-10-23-17:00 16.55 18.75 3.30 25.20
    2018-10-23-18:00 13.04 13.00 4.76 27.36
    2018-10-23-19:00 11.45 10.90 352.41 25.56
    2018-10-23-20:00 10.21 11.12 330.95 25.56
    2018-10-23-21:00 9.14 11.98 327.26 26.64
    2018-10-23-22:00 8.48 12.90 337.01 29.88
    2018-10-23-23:00 7.99 12.25 335.70 31.32
```

It works well, we stiil have a few différence between the leng of the vectors, i dont really know if the time 2 is good but it seems to correct the leng.
I dont see any difference between the different 2 scales.

### I try to find a calculation to get shorter vectors without changing the direction, in my head this is a mathematical transformation, so we will have something witch will be close to a arrow and not a vector.

Thanks for the tips, but when i put  head fixed it dont change anythings.

[image]

Here is what I get with LEN=0.4

```
LEN=0.4

set style arrow 1 head fixed filled size screen 0.03,15,135 ls 1

plot FILE using 1:3 with lines          # just to get the scaling
#SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN))
SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / ((GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)) * (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN) * GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE
plot \
    FILE using 1:3:(LEN*cos($4-180)*SCALE):(1.5*LEN*sin($4-180)) with vectors arrowstyle 1  title"Directions" ,\
    FILE using 1:3 smooth csplines  title "Vitesse",\
    FILE using 1:5 smooth csplines t "Rafale"
```

And this one with LEN=0.2
[image]

May be I do something wrong, but i like the first one and it look like what i want to do.

Thank you guys

Comment: O yes I see, the diretion 2 seems to keep proportion better. Do you know hoa to change the lend of the vector with out changing the size of the arrows ?

Comment: Change the `LEN` value

Comment: if i go under one the leng and the size of the arrow get smaller, they are proportionnal, or i miss somthing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Probably you must use the `fixed` parameter, `plot ... with vectors head fixed`

Comment: If you put LEN=0.2, the vector is really small but the head of the vector also. I would like a small arrow with a big head. For correction of the leng i use 1.5*LEN*sin($4) and just LEN for cos.

Comment: Like I wrote: Use `plot ... with vectors head fixed` which keeps the arrow head size. For a larger header, use the `size` parameter, see `help style arrow`

Answer (score 1):

Plot once to load the state variables `GPVAL_*`. Then replot using scaled values for the arrow xdelta and ydelta. Probably you want some additional correction so that the arrows are a reasonable size. Call that LEN.

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 with points          # just to get the scaling
SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:(LEN*cos($3)*SCALE):(LEN*sin($3)) with vectors
```

Comment: If the wind direction is in terms of the whole canvas, independent of the axes, then you must also take into account the `GPVAL_TERM_*` values: `SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN) * (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN) * GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE`